# How do you fully install IEEEtran for MacOS?

Tags: ieeetran, mac, texshop, mactex

I have been searching for hours trying to figure this out. [I need to write a paper in IEEE double column format for a graduate class.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/171892/ieee-two-column-format) Because LaTeX, I figured there was a package to help me make sure everything was formatted properly and there was! [The IEEEtran package comes to the rescue!](https://ctan.org/pkg/ieeetran)

I was saved! Just import it- `\documentclass{ieeetran}` and I should be good. Well, I was wrong.

`! LaTeX Error: File 'ieeetran.cls' not found.`

[The official documentation does not explain how this package is supposed to be installed.](http://ctan.math.utah.edu/ctan/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/IEEEtran/IEEEtran_HOWTO.pdf) You kinda need it installed to be able to even use it...

Someone on this forum said that it should be automatically installed by default with LaTeX, but that [I should just use the TeX Live Utility to have it install and prep everything for me](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12102/how-do-i-install-ctan-packages-on-mac-os-with-texshop). Looked through the packages and lo and behold! It was already there. Tried reinstalling the package, same error. Fine, let's try something else.

After trying for hours and [searching for where some files are](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10868/accessing-mac-mactex-install-folder) and [are not supposed to be placed](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58268/where-does-basictex-put-the-texmf-directory-on-osx), I realized that the `.cls` file *is* installed. In the "right" place (not where that last link said it was, but actually at `‎⁨Macintosh HD⁩/usr⁩/local/texlive/2018⁩/texmf-dist⁩/tex⁩/latex⁩/IEEEtran⁩`), however it is *akchtually* called `IEEEtran.cls` not `ieeetran.cls`. Fine, whatever LaTeX. You win. Tried it and it worked. I can now `\documentclass{IEEEtran}`. Yay.

Tried to compile, and I ran into a different error (yay!) on the exact same line (nay!):

`! LaTeX Error: File 'IEEEtran.sty' not found.`

I saw that after that it said `Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed, or enter a new name. (Default extension: sty) Enter file name:`

Ok cool! The `.sty` file I found in the same directory as the `.cls` file is named `IEEEtrantools.sty` for some reason but whatever, still `IEEEtran`. Tried it and got back: `The IEEEtrantools package is not for use with classes that already provide it.`

I am tired of this. How do you properly and fully install IEEEtran for LaTeX/TeXShop for MacOS?

Every single article I've found has been [unhelpful](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73016/how-do-i-install-an-individual-package-on-a-linux-system), [asking about Windows](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28198/using-ieeetrantools), [unhelpful *and* asking about Windows](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/83442/file-ieeetran-sty-not-found-trying-to-use-ieee-bibliography-style-with-bibte), [unhelpful and for Linux (which I thought MacOS *was*...?)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/255613/tex-live-2015-fundamental-package-texlive-infra-not-present), or [asking about Windows and marked as a duplicate](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/267277/latex-error-file-ieeetran-cls-not-found/452732). I have now linked 11 different pages, do not mark this as a duplicate if you try to link one of those pages.

Comment: What about using `\documentclass{IEEEtran}` as specified in the manual for the package/class?

Comment: `Just import it- \usepackage{ieeetran} and I should be good.` How did you figure that out? How did you come up with this?

Comment: My bad, I have `\documentclass{IEEEtran{` on the first line, I haven't even been able to get the compiler to get to the `\usepackage{IEEEtran}` on the next line. Editing to update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For future users who come across this post, the package names are CaSe SeNsItIvE, and you do not need to `\usepackage{package}` if you already set the `\documentclass{}` to that same package. If you have done both of those, boot up TeX Live Utility, make sure the package is updated and/or reinstall it. If that all doesn't work, ask another question.

Comment: You do realize that case sensitivity is a macOS feature and not a crazy strange LaTeX mystery?

Comment: I did not - all of the packages I have used thus far have been completely lowercase so I was under the impression that was just kinda the standard

Answer (score 1):

You remarked,

> I am tired of this B.S. How do you properly and fully install IEEEtran for LaTeX/TeXShop for MacOS?

Relax! All files related to the `IEEEtran` document class are already there -- no need to install anything afresh.

You just have to remember that LaTeX (and plain-TeX) syntax is case-sensitive under MacOS (and other OSs too, I suppose). Hence, `\documentclass{IEEEtran}` and `\documentclass{ieeetran}` are not at all the same. Only the first form "works".

Likewise, since `IEEEtran` is a LaTeX document class rather than a LaTeX package, neither `\usepackage{IEEEtran}` nor `\usepackage{ieeetran}` can possibly work.

Note that `IEEEtrantools.sty` has filename extension `.sty`. Hence, it is indeed a LaTeX package, and the correct way to load it -- should you have the need to do so -- is `\usepackage{IEEEtrantools}`. Just don't type `\usepackage{ieeetrantools}`.

Comment: It still doesn't work if I use `\usepackage{IEEEtrantools}` instead of `\usepackage{IEEEtran}`. Gives me the `The IEEEtrantools package is not for use with classes that already provide it.` error

Comment: I realized though, that you don't need to `\usepackage{IEEE}` if you already `\documentclass{IEEE}`

Comment: @elkshadow5 - Please note that I in no way recommended loading the IEEEtrantools package if the document class (e.g., `IEEEtran`) provides its functionality. My answer was purely about proper LaTeX syntax, i.e., about distinguishing between (a) uppercase and lowercase spellings and (b) document classes (filename extension: `cls`) and packages (filename extension: `sty`).